# Can I multiply pattern match in SED address to print

Tags: regex, sed

I have:

```
/.*213[0-9]\{3\}.*/ {p}
```

printing all lines with a 6 digit number beginning `213`

but would like to update to print all lines with a 6 digit number beginning `213` or `214`

Was thinking this should work:

```
/.*213[0-9]\{3\}.*|.*214[0-9]\{3\}.*/ {p}
```

or

```
/.*213|214[0-9]\{3\}.*/ {p}
```

but I think the syntax or logic is wrong.

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: `/.*(213|214)[0-9]\{3\}.*/ {p}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
/.*21[34][0-9]\{3\}.*/ {p}
```

Expanded command,

```
sed -n '/.*21[34][0-9]\{3\}.*/{p}' file
```

- see the regex part ,`/.*21[34][0-9]\{3\}.*/`. In this, the first number must be `2`, and the second number must be `1` and the third number `[34]` must be 3 or 4 followed by any three digit number. Corresponding line would be printed if the condition is satisfied.